# print separately words between Slash

Tags: java, string, substring, stringbuilder, indexof

i want to retrieve text between slash(es) but print text with before and after slash

```
public class Divide {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder link = new StringBuilder("www.entekhab.ir/fa/news/280809/");
        System.out.println(link+"\n");
        divideLink(link);
    }

    static void divideLink (StringBuilder link){
        String slash = "/";
        String divide = null;

        System.out.println("index of '"+slash+"' : ");

        for (int i = -1; (i = link.indexOf(slash, i + 1)) != -1; )  {
            System.out.print(i+" ");
            divide = link.substring(0, i);
            System.out.println(divide);
        }
    }
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
www.entekhab.ir/fa/news/280809/

index of '/' : 
15 www.entekhab.ir/
18 www.entekhab.ir/fa/
23 www.entekhab.ir/fa/news/
30 www.entekhab.ir/fa/news/280809/
```

i need  output like this:

```
www.entekhab.ir/fa/news/280809/

index of '/' : 
15 www.entekhab.ir
18 fa
23 news
30 280809
```

Comment: You don't phrase your problem clearly in my opinion, and my policy is to never read the code if the question in plain english is unclear. Could you clarify please ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void divideLink(String link) {
    System.out.println("index of '/':");
    int i = 0;
    for (String part : link.split("/")) {
        System.out.println((i += part.length()) + " " + part);
        i++;
    }
}
```